# Static member is in new spawned thread null

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

I have a really strange behavior, that could not be possible, how the code is written in java.
Static member is set and in e new spawned thread the member is null.
The member is not modified between the two breakpoints.

On another linux server it works without problems, maybe a jvm bug or some operating system bug?

It's not a race condition, because the other thread is spawned after the member is set.

**Details:**

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7

Tomcat 7.0.108

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.9.1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check whether you're using the same classloader in both cases? If you have a look at the first line in each stack trace there's the "owns: class<T> ... BridgeServlet)" with different ids (30 and 121) and this might indicate you're dealing with 2 different classes here (and thus 2 different class loaders).

Comment: You are right! I never had this problem before because working only with one classloader and not with many, so in every separated loaded class can exists a singleton, never heard from that. thank you for the quick reply. Add a answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even within the same JVM process a class can exist multiple times due to classloaders. A class maybe loaded by multiple classloaders and thus you could run into situations like ClassCastExceptions stating `A cannot be cast to A` which indicates that both classes named `A` are loaded by different classloaders.

Multiple classloaders can be used in many applications but Application servers are a prominent example, e.g. due to the fact that web applications need to be isolated from each other and thus must not be able to access each other's classes.

That being said, have a look at your thread stacks, in both the first line is:

```
owns Class<T> (org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet) (id=xx)
```

but in both cases the id (which should be the id of the `Class` instance) is different: 30 and 121

So you're using 2 different instances of `BridgeServlet.class` (loaded by different classloaders) and thus you have the same static field multiple times.